# Using Route Parameter return the view incomplete and without Css [Laravel 5]

Tags: html, laravel, routes

When I user this Route :

```
Route::get('home', function()
{
   return View::make('index');
});
```

with URL:

> localhost/laravel/public/home

It get the view and **works well** .

**But** when use this Route:

```
Route::get('home/{id}', function($id)
{
    return View::make('index')->with('id', $id);
});
```

with URL:

> localhost/laravel/public/home/10

It the view but **doesn't work well** that view come without any CSS, JS, .. etc

I can't define the ERROR here ?!

Comment: Is there a reason you not pointing the servers' document root to Laravel's `public` directory?

Comment: Can make it more clear please, I'm new with laravel !!

Comment: The HTTP server you're using has a directive that allows you to set the directory that is visible for public requests. That is called the **document root**. I'll assume you're using either [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) (because they're the most common), and you can search for examples on how to configure the document root for any of them. It might also help if you can give more info regarding your enviroment Windows, Linux, OSX? And how are you managing your software stack?

Comment: Also try adding this line `<base href="http://localhost/laravel/public/">` to the `<head>` section of your pages . Depending on how the path of your resources is defined this might fix the issue. However I still strongly suggest that you take the approach I suggested in my previous comments.

Comment: Ok it's work well now, after adding this line <base href="http://localhost/laravel/public/"> to <head> Thansks :)

Comment: For me, it solved with this line at <head>: <base href="/public">

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, I know this might be very late for this question, but I also got the same problem and stuck in the same situation.
After reading and researching on google, I got the answer.
I hope it may help someone.

This problems occurrs because we are using the `relative path` in our `blade template` and the `solution` is so simple, We have to use only the `asset` function to overcome this problem.

So change your code like this...

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"> </script>
```

Hope that helps.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Controller :

```
public function Details($id){
        $demandes=DB::select('SELECT * FROM demande where id_demande=? ',[$id]);
        $buts=DB::select('SELECT * FROM but where id_demande=? ',[$id]);
        return view('details')->with(array('demandes'=>$demandes ,'buts'=>$buts));
    }
```

Web.php :

```
Route::get('/Details/{id}','DemandeController@Details')->name('Details');
```

Blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.mainlayout')
@section('content')
//code
@endsection
```

The problem is the blade is not loading css and Js 
So you need to put this code in the `<head>` ----> `<base href="/public">`

Answer (score 0):

Run this..

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

source: [Laravel frontend docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

Answer (score 0):

OK, its a old thread, but here is my solution for records.

I've put ../ in front of my existing resource e.g

```
<script src="js/front.js"></script>
```

became

```
<script src="../js/front.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

as answered above not only for resources that are called from the header in your blade but for effectiveness ensure that all other resources within your blade are also referenced using the **asset()** method such as when referencing images/ videos without your page.